# Angular - ng grid select next/previous item grammatically with grouping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, navigation, grouping

I'm trying to navigate between the ng-grid entities(rows) using 
next and previous buttons while the grid has grouping. Here's my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Custom Plunker</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions"></div>
        <button ng-click="goNext()">Next</button>
        <button ng-click="goPrevious()">Previous</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// main.js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    var selectedRowIdx=-1;
    $scope.nav = false;
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                      {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                      {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                      {name: "Moroni", age: 53},
                      {name: "Moroni", age: 54},
                      {name: "Tiancum", age: 44},
                      {name: "Tiancum", age: 45},
                      {name: "Moroni", age: 51},
                      {name: "Moroni", age: 52},
                      {name: "Jacob", age: 28}];
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    multiSelect: false,
    groups: ['name'],
    showGroupPanel: true,
    groupsCollapsedByDefault: false,

    beforeSelectionChange:function(row,evt){
    console.log('before');  
      return true;
    },
    afterSelectionChange: function(row, event) {
      console.log('after');
      if ($scope.nav){
        $scope.nav = false;
        return;
      }
      if (row.selected){
        console.log(row);
        console.log($scope.nav);
       selectedRowIdx = row.rowIndex;
       //console.log(selectedRowIdx);
      }

    }
  };
  $scope.count = 0;
  //ngGridEventData gets emitted after all functions in watch for data changes     

  $scope.selectEnosRow = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.myData, function(data, index) {
      if (data.name == 'Enos') {
        $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(index, true);
      }
    })
  };
  $scope.goPrevious = function(){
     $scope.nav = true;
    $scope.gridOptions.selectItem(selectedRowIdx - 1, true);  
  };  
  $scope.goNext = function(){
     $scope.nav = true;
    $scope.gridOptions.selectRow(selectedRowIdx + 1, true);  
  };  

});
```

The problem occurs when I'm clicking on the next/previous action,
instead of selecting the actual next item inside the group -> 
the next element from the grid configuration is being selected!

I've created plunker to demonstrate my problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/sk6xme6aXDvQoB3yZ21M?p=preview

To see the problem click on the first item in the first group and then click next()..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/mv4BGznmjhCb1faeWeZl?p=preview

I added a init sort

```
sortInfo: {fields:['name'], directions:['desc']},
```

and you used in the goPrevious

```
$scope.gridOptions.selectItem(selectedRowIdx - 1, true);
```

instead of

```
$scope.gridOptions.selectRow(selectedRowIdx - 1, true);
```

Edit:
If you need the index in your data from an index after sort you can use this

```
$scope.gridOptions.ngGrid.rowMap.indexOf(selectedRowIdx);
```

Comment: do you know what should I have to change in case I want this navigation to be only inside the groups.. ?

Comment: than you have to compare the name of the selected with the name of the selected + / - 1 and only select the next/prev if they are equal